# Azure SDK for Ruby: Table Storage - query_entities page, count, skip entities?

Tags: ruby, azure

Couldn't really find a proper way to get a count of entities in table storage. Max resultset = 1000, tried using inlinecount and skip ODATA queries but no success so far.

e.g.:

> query = { :inlinecount => 'allpages', :filter => ... }
>
> result => azure_table_service.query_entities("table_name", query).count

or:

> query = { :skip => 1000, :filter => ... }
>
> result = azure_table_service.query_entities("table_name", query).count

Any ideas on how to do this (and obviously keep the count operation on the server)?

**Edit based on responses:**
I'm well aware of "how wrong" this really is. I know it's horribly slow and not the way to go. This is not for production use. I'm looking into a way to fetch some metrics from my data in table storage, ad-hoc, using ruby, without modifying the actual cloud app. This code runs locally on my laptop. Somehow, *I can't retrieve the continuation token to page the table*.

Comment: What language are you using? Just to understand - Are you trying to find total entities in a table?

Comment: Ruby ... it is in the question "title" itself :)

Comment: @GauravMantri Ruby SDK :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot that easily get the count of table entities in any language. to understand why, you have to go through the [Understanding Table Service Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179463.aspx). [Query Timeout and Pagination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135718.aspx) and [Querying Table and Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx) in particular.

The table service does not support/maintain total number of records property per table. One of the reasons is that table data may be scattered across literally hundreds of servers. Going with Table Storage you have to ask yourself do you really want to to know the total number of records and what does a number like `468 129 439 781` mean in the context of your application? Will it really help you to structure your pagination logic?

The only way that I am aware of, to get the total number of records in an Azure Table is to perform a query without filter condition and recursively repeat it until you have no continuation token in the response, counting the number of returned entities for each call. This will take huge amount of time/bandwidth/storage transaction resources.

**Update based on comments**

If would like to have some metrics, please first check the [How to monitor Storage Accounts](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/storage/how-to-monitor-a-storage-account/) and verify there isn't already something that will help you.

Then if you still want to go on your own, I highly suggest that you use a web traffic analyzer tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to capture and examine requests and responses you sent from your Ruby app. The missing continuation token issue might just be in the Ruby SDK itself. First make sure it comes in the response. A Table Continuation token will be in the response if there is no filter specified and table contains more than 1000 records, or time to complete request is not enough to retrieve all the records in the table (given it has less than 1000 records).

Comment: Thank you for the links. Yep, i'm well aware of "how wrong" this really is :) I was only looking into a means for a retrospective analysis of certain metrics in my data (this is not part of the cloud app). In this particular case, I'm looking for the continuation token though (which is always null if I follow the SDK sample).